# Determine when a Range attribute is valid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view model I have two properties with `Range` attributes. Both values must be non-negative.

```
[Required]
[Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Principal must be positive.")]
public double Principal { get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(0.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Interest must be positive.")]
public double Interest { get; set; }

public double Total { get; set; }
```

The third property `Total` will be the sum of `Principal` and `Interest`. This sum will be calculated and updated with Javascript every time the user enters a valid value in `Principal` or `Interest`.

How can I detect when a new, **valid**, non-negative amount has been entered in either of these fields?

If I were using a custom attribute this would be easy. I could simply perform the calculation whenever the custom jQuery unobtrusive function found a positive value. The unobtrusive function would tell me if the value was valid.

Maybe I should just detect key up and then perform the calculation if the value is positive. This seems redundant though since jQuery unobtrusive is already doing this same thing.

Comment: calculation vs validation is not redundant. Your validation script isn't going to do your calcs

Comment: no but it checks if it's valid. I really only want to do the calculation when the value is valid.

Comment: You can use jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and then call the below function inside javascript.

$(function () {
        var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        settngs.onfocusout = function (element) { $(element).valid(); };
    });